# SQL Join another lookup table in a pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, pivot

I have a table called Grades in my database for recording pupil grades as points for every year and term they attend.  These points are converted to GCSE results using a lookup table.  Although I can return the Points using a pivot table, I'm not sure how to return a table subsituting the points for GCSE grades.

My Grades table looks like this:

```
PupilID, GradeSubject, YearAndTerm, Grade
10001, English, Y7T1, 81
10001, English, Y7T2, 85
10001, English, Y7T3, 92
```

My GradesToPoints lookup table looks like this:

```
PointGrade, GCSEGrade
80, E-
81, E
82, E+
83, D-
84, D
```

I have the following SQL statement which returns a table with the columns I need but with points, I want each column (Y7T1, Y7T2, etc) to return the GCSE grade for that point by using the lookup table GradesToPoints.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT PupilID, GradeSubject, YearAndTerm, Grade  
    FROM Grades  
    ) AS DT
PIVOT(SUM(Grade) FOR YearAndTerm IN ([KeyStage2],[Y7T1],[Y7T2],[Y7T3], 
    [Y8T1],[Y8T2],[Y8T3],[Y9T1],[Y9T2],[Y9T3],[Y10T1],[Y10T2],[Y10T3],
    [Y11T1],[Y11T2],[Y11T3],[Y12T1],[Y12T2],[Y12T3],[Y13T1],[Y13T2],
    [Y13T3],[Y14T1],[Y14T2],[Y14T3])) AS PVT
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `SUM` aggregate was just a dummy. I had to change it to `MIN` so it will work with a char column. The key is in the inner join which needs to be done prior to the pivot.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT g.PupilID, g.GradeSubject, g.YearAndTerm, g2p.GCSEGrade
    FROM Grades as g INNER JOIN GradesToPoints as g2p on g2p.PointGrade = g.Grade
    ) AS DT
PIVOT(MIN(GCSEGrade) FOR YearAndTerm IN ([KeyStage2],[Y7T1],[Y7T2],[Y7T3], 
    [Y8T1],[Y8T2],[Y8T3],[Y9T1],[Y9T2],[Y9T3],[Y10T1],[Y10T2],[Y10T3],
    [Y11T1],[Y11T2],[Y11T3],[Y12T1],[Y12T2],[Y12T3],[Y13T1],[Y13T2],
    [Y13T3],[Y14T1],[Y14T2],[Y14T3])) AS PVT
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. This creates a single new column called GCSEGrade with a GCSE grade in.  I dont want this, I want the GCSE grade to be under the columns Y7T1, Y7T2, Y7T3, etc, instead of the points which currently appear under them

Comment: Try listing just the columns you need rather than `*`. I've made a few edits to the query, in case you ran an older version. (I had accidentally left in the old Grade column inside the pivot operator.)

Comment: This works great, does exactly what I need.  Why do you suggest using the column names rather than * ?

Comment: I was thinking extra columns will change the pivot. But I guess that wasn't the problem anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to list all the rows even if the value for Grade is NULL?

Comment: Try changing the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.